# How do I freeze a row in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

Given some sheet I'm able to freeze the current row by typing "freeze" into the `Help` menu as shown:

[image: screen shot using "freeze" in 'Help' menu]

But I'm curious:

- Where is the `Freeze` option in the menu bar?
- What are the keyboard shortcuts to freeze/un-freeze rows/cols on Mac/Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Freeze` option is found in the `View` menu:

[image: screen shot of the 'Freeze' option in the 'View' menu]

Unfortunately, there is no [keyboard shortcut](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110) for freezing/unfreezing any part of the sheet. (The closest is that there is a shortcut to open the `View` menu.)

Answer (score -1):

Freeze rows and columns in Google Sheets Mobile app
On the Google Sheets Android or iOS app, it’s actually even more easy to [freeze a row or column](https://www.brankaspedia.com/2020/07/cara-membekukan-freeze-baris-atau-kolom-google-sheets.html). Here’s how:

Open the sheet and tap on the “Sheet” tab at the bottom.

Now scroll down and you will see two options “Freeze rows” and “Freeze columns”. Click on the upward and downward arrow next to them to select the number of rows and columns you want to freeze. A gray line will indicate the selected rows and columns.

You can decrease or increase the number as needed, and you can unfreeze them by setting the number to 0.

Comment: The text in the linked article appears to be Indonesian, I don't think that will be of much help.

Comment: This site is about using web applications, why it's better to use the mobile apps rather the web app for this case?